# Need a more effective way to loop through a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I need a better script than the one below. I can't add html to it. Can't even add a ";" between records. I also want to be able to add html and list the data easily like in: members.Name and members.Expires and sort the data. Is there a more fluid, basic way that would facilitate my requirements?

I have this json:

```
var members = [
    {"Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed", "Expires": "2017.10.05"},
    {"Name": "Attaya, James", "Expires": "2018.01.12"}
    ];
```

and this script:

```
<script>

var divId = document.getElementById("json")
for(var i=0;i<members.length;i++)

for(var keys in members[i]){
console.log(keys +"-->"+members[i][keys]);
divId.innerHTML = divId.innerHTML + "  " +members[i][keys];
}

</script>
```

Comment: Don't `innerHTML +=`. Build the whole markup first and then add it to the DOM at once.

Comment: You should add your expected output because it's not clear from your question.

Comment: I got it. Thomas, you are right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked nicely: simpler and more versatile:

```
<script>
var divId = document.getElementById("json")
string = "";

for(var i=0;i<members.length;i++) {
string += members[i].Name + " " + members[i].Expires +" &#9679; ";

}

divId.innerHTML = string;
</script>
```